# Game with Achievement system

Tags: patent-infringement, microsoft, video-games, us7887419

I saw this patent own by microsoft.

http://www.google.com/patents/US20060122716

I want to make a game that give a small reward for player who complete some task in game something like kill 50 zombies, headshot 50 times.and there will be a list of achievement that will collect an information about detail and did player complete it already?

Example for my game's achievement system idea is in many game in iOS,android and etc.

I want to make sure on this since i found a lot of silly(in my opinion) sue about patent in a news like patent trolling.

So i want to ask a question.

Is my game's achievement system is same with the one own by microsoft and  will i be sued for making a game with this achievement system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you posted is an application. It has not issued and is not enforceable so there is no way you could infringe any of the claims.

http://www.google.com/patents/US7887419

That is the issued patent and the claims are much narrower and more specific.

If after reading that you are truly concerned about infringement you should contact an attorney.